# YUI + jQuery long press action and default click

Tags: jquery, frameworks, yui

I currently write project using YUI(app framework). A have some actions for each elements( going to another page, clear etc.). I want to add long press action to each button. Unfortunately YUI doesn't support this kind of stuff. I found solution in jQuery:

```
 var pressTimer

$("a").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer)
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { ... your code ...},1000)
  return false; 
});
```

And here is my question. How to add this feature to my current code? Writing new function doesn't work, so does adding this code to existing function.

//edited
My code looks like this:

```
//stuff
events: {
'.button': {
click: 'select'
}
},
```

And then there is select function:

```
select: function (e) {
//code
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear as what you're asking? that function works btw is that's what you're asking

Comment: Generally I don't know exactly how to connect this long press with my existing code. I forgott to wrtie that I'm using events(if it helps). Writing new events didn't fix my problem.

Comment: can you add custom events like this? http://jsfiddle.net/NbJPq/2/. Or use trigger('click') that will trigger your events click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI has a concept called Synthetic events. These events are fake DOM events that you define to behave in a similar way as `$(foo).trigger('myFooEvent')` in jQuery. Defining a synthetic event is just a matter of calling `Y.Event.define()`. In your case it would look something like this:

```
Y.Event.define('longpress', {
  on: function (node, sub, notifier) {
    var timeout;

    sub._downHandle = node.on('mousedown', function (e) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        notifier.fire('longpress', {domEvent: e});
      }, 1000);
    });
    sub._upHandle = node.on('mouseup', function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
  },
  detach: function (node, sub) {
    sub._downHandle.detach();
    sub._upHandle.detach();
  }
});
```

After defining a synthetic event all you have to do to use it is call `node.on('myevent')`. For example: `Y.one('#foo').on('longpress', fn)`.

The YUI App Framework uses event delegation, so you're going to have to add support for event delegation to your synthetic event. I suggest that you read the Synthetic Events section of the [Event User Guide](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#synthetic-events) and follow the [Creating an Arrow Event for DOM subscription](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/synth-example.html) example.

After setting up your event you should be able to use it in the app framework as you would any other event:

```
events: {
  '.button': {
    'longpress': fn
  }
}
```